# Find all pairs in an array which are rotations of one another

Tags: arrays

I was recently asked a coding question where I had to find all pairs in an array such that they are rotations of one another.

Rotation of 456 : 456->645->564.

When the array is `arr=[13,31,12,456,564]`, the output should be `[(13,31),(456,564)]`

Here is my approach in **O(n^2 *k)** time complexity, where `n` is the **length** of the array and `k` is the **average length** of a string in the array.

```
for i =0 to n do:
  temp=string(arr[i])+string(arr[i]) 
  for j=i+1 to n do:
        if string(arr[j]) in temp: 
            print(arr[i],arr[j])
```

I want to optimize the time complexity. I need suggestions.

Comment: In which language are you attempting?

Comment: python, but I just wrote in general  pseudocode